# Is Oracle's syntax diagram for PL/SQL blocks wrong?

Tags: parsing, plsql, sql

I suspect that the syntax diagram for a `plsql_block` as given in the 
*Oracle® Database PL/SQL Language Reference* for Relese 2 is wrong.
(For reference, [here's the current link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/block.htm) to that document)

The following piece of PL/SQL compiles fine:

```
declare

  cursor 
    cursor_definition 
  is select * from dual;

  variable_declaration number;

begin
  null;
end;
```

The following statements are assumptions that I make based on the piece of PL/SQL above and based on Oracle's syntax diagram.

1. The declare section (above) consists of a `cursor definition` followed by a `variable declaration` (which in turn is an `item declaration`).
2. An `item declaration` can *only* be an element of an `item list 1`.
3. A `cursor definition` can *only* be an element of an `item list 2`.
4. An `item list 2` can never be followed by an `item list 1`.

Now, the `variable declaration` following the `cursor definition` contradicts *point 4*. Therefore I conclude that the
syntax diagram is wrong.

Maybe I am overlooking something, in which case I'd be *very* grateful for pointing this out to me.

Please understand that a wrong syntax diagram per se is no big deal to me. But I am in the process of writing a PL/SQL parser
and the parser stumbles for the exact situation given with the example PL/SQL code. So, in order to improve the parser, I'd like
to have a more authorative sequence diagram.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what tool are you developing this parser with?

Comment: Adam, you won't probably believe me, but I am writing the parser with PL/SQL...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I concur. The syntax diagrams explicitly state that a `plsql_block` is effectively `item_list_2` preceded by an optional `item_list_1`.

Further, cursor *definitions* (with the `is` bit) can only occur in `item_list_2` and variable declarations (with or without an `=`) are part of the `item_declaration` set and can therefore only be in `item_list_1`.

Those facts make your code sample incorrect so, if it manages to compile, then either:

- the syntax diagrams are wrong; or
- the compiler doesn't follow them to the letter; or
- your looking at code that's covered by *different* syntax diagrams.

On that last bullet point, interestingly enough, the [syntax diagrams for 11.1](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/block.htm#i32791) are slightly different.

The declare section can be `item_list_1` or `item_list_2` or `item_list_1` followed by `item_list_2`.

Where it gets interesting is that `item_list_1` can have any number of `item_declaration` entries and this includes both `variable_declaration` and `cursor_declaration`.

In 11.1, a `cursor_declaration` can be either a declaration *or* a definition, based on the language elements in 11.2 (in other words, there is no `cursor_definition` type since the declaration allows both in the declaration).

So what you have is perfectly valid in 11.1 so the first thing I'd check is that you're actually *running* 11.2 where that successful compilation is taking place.

It's still possible of course that you're running 11.2 and the syntax diagrams are wrong, in which case you should complain bitterly to Oracle but I don't know what sort of a response you'll get from a company whose flagship database product can't tell the difference between an empty `varchar` and a NULL <sup>(a)</sup>.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I'll never pass up an opportunity to mention this and advance the cause of my beloved DB2 :-)

Comment: I have successfully compiled it on Oracle 10 as well as 11.2 ... I wonder if there is any distinction between item_1 elements and item_2 elements *at all*?

Comment: @René Nyffenegger: Yes there is a distinction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180178/does-oracles-ps-sql-require-specific-ordering-of-entries-in-the-declare-sectio

Comment: @Shannon: thanks for your clarication and the question you posted out of it.