# Does Oracle's PS/SQL require specific ordering of entries in the `declare` section of a block

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the question "[Is Oracle's syntax diagram for PL/SQL blocks wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174937/is-oracles-syntax-diagram-for-pl-sql-blocks-wrong)"
[René Nyffenegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180275/rene-nyffenegger) showed how Oracle allows cursor definitions to
preceed variable declarations in the declare section of a block in
spite of [Oracle's documenation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/block.htm) indicated that this was
not allowed. And asked if he was missing anything.

[Paxdiablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7174937/is-oracles-syntax-diagram-for-pl-sql-blocks-wrong/7175179#7175179) concurred with René's reading of the documentation
that a cursor definition can not come prior to a variable declaration,
since variable declarations are only allowed in item_list_1, cursor
definitions are only allowed in item_list_2 and item_list_1 comes
before item_list_2.

René commented, "I wonder if there is any distinction between item_1
elements and item_2 elements at all?" In my words, "Is there any
ordering required between different types of entries in the declare
section of a block?"

Answer (score 3):

As of Oracle 10g R2 the answer is yes, there is a required ordering
between items in item_list_1 and item_list_2, even if cursor
definitions are allowed out of place.

For example a procedure definition is not allowed before a variable declaration:

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
----------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 10g Enterprise Edition Release 10.2.0.4.0 - 64bi
PL/SQL Release 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    10.2.0.4.0  Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 10.2.0.4.0 - Production

SQL> declare
  2      variable_declaration number;
  3      procedure procedure_definition is begin
  4          null;
  5      end procedure_definition;
  6  begin
  7      null;
  8  end;
  9  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> declare
  2      procedure procedure_definition is begin
  3          null;
  4      end procedure_definition;
  5      variable_declaration number;
  6  begin
  7      null;
  8  end;
  9  /
    variable_declaration number;
    *
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 5, column 5:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "VARIABLE_DECLARATION" when expecting one of the following:
begin function package pragma procedure form
ORA-06550: line 8, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:
end not pragma final instantiable order overriding static
member constructor map
```

Answer (score 1):

I *think* (based on *very limited empric* tests) that after the first `procedure definition` or `function definItion` nothing but further `procedure definitions` or `function definitions` are allowed.

So, `variable declarations` (or more generally an `item declarations`), `cursor declarations`, `type definitions` and so on should be `item 1 elems` and (probably only) `function definitions` and `procedure definitions` should be `item 2 elems` (and only `item 2 elems`).

(Only?) `function declarations` and `procedure declarations` are (or seem to be) permitted in both the `item 1 elems` and `item 2 elems`.

Comment: Was that on 11gR2? I don't have 11gR2 handy, it does appear that what you describe is 10gR2 behavior, matches the error message in my answer. Also it is the behavior described in the 10gR2 documentation: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/block_declaration.htm#sthref2482

Comment: Yes, that was on a 10gR2. I won't be able to touch an 11gR2 until Monday.